# Having a new list<> in each for loop iteration

Tags: c#

I am trying to having a new list added on every for loop iteration. I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < torni.Length; i++)
{
    List<string> torni+i = // STUCK HER
}
```

Listnames should be like torni0, torni1, torni2 ......

Would really appreciate your assistance. Thanks!!

Comment: You can't create variables names on the fly like that in C#.  What problem are you actually trying to solve?  There is probably some more direct way to accomplish it.

Comment: Are you trying to create a list of lists?

Comment: Just to clear things, On every iteration, I need to make a new list which would require a different list name

Comment: A new list does not require a "different list name". Would a list of lists solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this that would be slightly different would be to make a list of lists and then each index would be a discrete list.

You can't dynamically generate variable names in c#

like this:

```
tornis = new List<List<String>>()
for (int i = 0; i < torni.Length; i++)
{
    tornis.append(new List<String>())
}
```

Alternatively as DanH Points out a dictionary of lists

```
tornis = new Dictionary<String,List<String>()
for (int i = 0; i < torni.Length; i++)
{
    tornis.add("torni" + i, new List<String>())
}
```

This will give you a dictionary with the keys of the convention you want and a list of lists.

Comment: If you need to name the lists you could use a Dictionary<string, List<string>>().

Answer (score 0):

If you need each list only for the duration of a single loop iteration, then you don't need different list names:

```
for (int i = 0; i < torni.Length; i++)
{
    List<string> temporaryList = new List<string>();

    // use the list here
}
```